# Update value in ConcurrentDictionary by condition

Tags: c#, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have class:

```
public class LazyConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>> _concurrentDictionary;
    public LazyConcurrentDictionary()
    {
        _concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>();
    }

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
    {
        var lazyResult = _concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key,
            k => new Lazy<TValue>(() => valueFactory(k), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication));
        return lazyResult.Value;
    }
}
```

I want use this class for manage token.
A token expired in 2 hours.

```
var dictionary = new LazyConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>();


var result = dictionary.GetOrAdd("80", k => new Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>(() =>
{
    return new Tuple<string, DateTime>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTime.Now);
}));
```

For example for key 80 have value tuple with token and datetime now.
How do change code when time expired get new token?
best regards

Comment: Related: [Enforce an async method to be called lazily on demand, and called again when the previous result has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467426/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-lazily-on-demand-and-called-again-when-the).

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias.No exception is supposed to be thrown, there will always be a token.

Comment: The value type is `Lazy<Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>`, is this what you desire?

Comment: Hi @shingo.I read this article .https://endjin.com/blog/2015/10/using-lazy-and-concurrentdictionary-to-ensure-a-thread-safe-run-once-lazy-loaded-collection

Comment: I think that Shingo means that the type of the `dictionary` should be `LazyConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<string, DateTime>>`, since the `Lazy` is already part of the `LazyConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And the article just instroduced a thread-safe and lazy-loaded collection, why do you think it is suitable for your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List with timeout/expire ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493064/list-with-timeout-expire-ability)

Comment: @shingo .List not handle concurency

Comment: Please read the content, don't just look at the title.

Comment: Thanks @shingo . I am not idea for that link

Comment: Related: [How can I make this Concurrent Dictionary expire with a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232963/how-can-i-make-this-concurrent-dictionary-expire-with-a-timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting an access token generally implies a network call. In this scenario asynchronous programming is a win. So let's define a delegate that returns an access token asynchronously for a given key:

```
public record class AccessToken(string TokenValue, DateTime ExpiresAt);

public delegate Task<AccessToken> TokenFactoryAsyncFunction(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Then you can use a concurrent dictionary to cache the tokens. However you cannot store the tokens in the dictionary because the factory is asynchronous. You need to store `Task<AccessToken>`. Futhermore, to avoid cache stampede because `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` may invoke serveral times the dictionary value factory function, you need to use `Lazy` values. So, at the end, you need to store `Lazy<Task<AccessToken>>` values in the dictionary.

With this in mind you can use the following `AccessTokenCache` class that caches the tokens and removes expired ones at intervals:

```
public sealed class AccessTokenCache : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly TokenFactoryAsyncFunction tokenFactory;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task<AccessToken>>> tokenCache = new();
    private readonly TimeSpan expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval;
    private readonly Task? expiredTokensRemovalTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public AccessTokenCache(TokenFactoryAsyncFunction tokenFactory, TimeSpan expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval)
    {
        if (tokenFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenFactory));
        }
        if (expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval != Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan && expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"invalid value for {nameof(expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval)}", nameof(expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval));
        }
        this.tokenFactory = tokenFactory;
        this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval = expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval;
        if (expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval > TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            this.expiredTokensRemovalTask = this.RemoveExpiredTokensAtIntervals(this.cts.Token);
        }
    }

    private async Task RemoveExpiredTokensAtIntervals(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(expiredTokensRemovalCheckInterval, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (var kv in this.tokenCache)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

                // better not to wait on non-completed tasks.
                if (kv.Value.Value.IsCompleted == false) continue;
                AccessToken accessToken;
                try
                {
                    accessToken = await GetAccessTokenRemovingWhenFaultedAsync(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // not rethrowing intentionally.
                    continue;
                }
                if (accessToken.ExpiresAt <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    this.tokenCache.TryRemove(kv);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Lazy<Task<AccessToken>> CreateLazyAccessTokenTask(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return new Lazy<Task<AccessToken>>(async () =>
        {
            using (var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, this.cts.Token))
            {
                return await this.tokenFactory(key, linkedCts.Token);
            }
        });
    }

    private Lazy<Task<AccessToken>> GetOrAdd(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return this.tokenCache.GetOrAdd(key, key => CreateLazyAccessTokenTask(key, cancellationToken));
    }
    private async Task<AccessToken> GetAccessTokenRemovingWhenFaultedAsync(string key, Lazy<Task<AccessToken>> lazyAccessTokenTask)
    {
        try
        {
            return await lazyAccessTokenTask.Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            // if you don't remove the key, getting an access token
            // for this key will fail forever.
            this.tokenCache.TryRemove(KeyValuePair.Create(key, lazyAccessTokenTask));
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<AccessToken> GetAccessTokenAsync(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(AccessTokenCache));
        var lazyAccessTokenTask = this.GetOrAdd(key, cancellationToken);
        var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenRemovingWhenFaultedAsync(key, lazyAccessTokenTask);
        if (accessToken.ExpiresAt <= DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            var newLazyAccessTokenTask = CreateLazyAccessTokenTask(key, cancellationToken);
            // several threads can see this token as expired at the same time
            // they will try to uptate it concurrently, but only one is successful
            if (this.tokenCache.TryUpdate(key, newLazyAccessTokenTask, lazyAccessTokenTask))
            {
                lazyAccessTokenTask = newLazyAccessTokenTask;
            }
            else
            {
                // TryUpdate failed because another thread updated it. So let's get it
                lazyAccessTokenTask = this.GetOrAdd(key, cancellationToken);
            }
            accessToken = await GetAccessTokenRemovingWhenFaultedAsync(key, lazyAccessTokenTask);
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) return;
        IsDisposed = true;
        using (this.cts)
        {
            this.cts.Cancel();
            if (this.expiredTokensRemovalTask != null)
            {
                await this.expiredTokensRemovalTask;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Inside the `RemoveExpiredTokensAtIntervals` you could ignore the non-completed tasks, instead of awaiting them. Also instead of `Task.Delay` you could use the simpler [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer), but this would make the API inaccessible to pre-.NET 6 projects.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ignoring non-completed tasks

Answer (score -1):

I use this Package [Dao.ConcurrentDictionaryLazy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dao.ConcurrentDictionaryLazy)

and this code is

```
 var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionaryLazy<string, Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>>();


            var result = dictionary.GetOrAdd("80", k => new Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>(() =>
              {

                  return new Tuple<string, DateTime>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3));
              }));

            Console.WriteLine($"dictionary: {result.Value.Item1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"dictionary 2: {result.Value.Item2}");

            if ((DateTime.Now - result.Value.Item2).Hours > 2)
                dictionary.TryRemove("80", out Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>> result2);

            result = dictionary.GetOrAdd("80", k => new Lazy<Tuple<string, DateTime>>(() =>
            {

                return new Tuple<string, DateTime>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTime.Now);
            }));

            Console.WriteLine($"dictionary: {result.Value.Item1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"dictionary 2: {result.Value.Item2}");

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The `ConcurrentDictionaryLazy` already incorporates a `Lazy<T>` for each value. Wrapping this `Lazy<T>` in another `Lazy<T>` is superfluous, and pure overhead.

Comment: Also pay attention to the difference between [`TimeSpan.Hours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.hours) and [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours).

Comment: Also the `DateTime.Now` is susceptible to Daylight saving time (DST) clock adjustments. Ideally you don't want to depend your timespan measurements on the system clock. That's why APIs like the [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) or the [`Environment.TickCount64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64) exist.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias if remove lazy when i get error in GetOrAdd